# Can I decide whether to deep copy and shallow copy in Python?

Tags: python, pointers

There's a pointer in C++, but I've heard that Python doesn't.

However, in the below example, in the class c1, I copied class c0 to c0.link_c.

I thought it should be done with the deep copy making a copied new instance of c0, but it did shallow copy just copying a pointer.

Can I make a decision whether to do deep copy or shallow copy in this case?

```
class Paraent:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 0
        self.c0 = Child()
        self.c1 = Child(c=self.c0)
    def exe(self, input):
        self.c1.exe(input)

class Child:
    def __init__(self, c=None):
        self.v0 = 0
        self.v1 = 1
        if c is not None:
            self.link_c = c
    def exe(self, input):
        self.link_c.v0 = input
        

p0 = Paraent()
p0.exe(3)
print(p0.c0.v0) ## 3 not 0
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html

Comment: Copying might be a super-duper-fundamental, incredibly common operation in C++, but it's nowhere near that in Python. `copy.deepcopy` technically exists, but it's very slow, kind of unreliable, and prone to copying more than you actually want - for example, if you had a `std:::vector<std::vector<std::shared_ptr<whatever>>>` in C++, you could easily copy the vectors without copying the pointed-to objects, but the closest equivalent in Python would copy the pointed-to objects as well.

Comment: In Python terminology, there's no copy being made here whatsoever. `p0.c1.link_c` is just another name for `p0.c0`. I don't know any lower-level language, but I believe you can think of that like a copy of a reference. If you want to actually copy `self.c0`, a Python shallow copy works: `Child(c=copy.copy(self.c0))`. [If anyone wants to put this into an answer, by all means, I'm just not confident enough about the details.]